# Going from a Modal View to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I go from a Modal ViewController under a Tab #1's ViewController to a ViewController under Tab #3 when the user hits the done button in the Modal VC?

I know how to pop the Modal VC and return the user to the ViewController that instantiated it but then the user still has to manually navigate himself to Tab #3.

Thanks in advance,

Hiren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate from a page to another page then this will be done in same tab if you want to change tab.

then you can use `[yourAppObj.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];`
from a page of 1 tab page to view third tab view.

make object for app delegate class for this import app delegate class then

```
yourAppDelegate *yourAppObj=(yourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

then you can use above line in you view.

Comment: I tried doing this but I get an error "Request for rootTabBarController in something not a structure or union".  Here's my code: UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[myApp.rootTabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];  //rootTabBarController is the name I used for the tabBarController in the appdelegate.

Comment: impoting the app delegate file is must